# visual studio built in compare overlaying

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am unable to compare files side by side, rather visual studio is just overlaying them onto the same document with green / red highlighting:

[image]

**How do I restore the default code comparison settings so that I can see the two versions of the same file side by side rather than on top of each other?**

This functionality broke when I uninstalled CodeCompare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your toolbar, there may be a `Compare Files` section that looks like this:[image: Compare Files toolbar.]

Click the left most icon, and change from `Inline mode` to `Side-by-side` mode.

Note: my hotkeys may be different from yours, since I have additional extensions installed.